# ¿Cómo saber qué input fue seleccionado con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente código con html, y está hecho para seleccionar solo un radio button

```
<div class="form-check" style="display:none;" id="contentRadioButton0">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="optionResult" id="option0" value="Dato 0">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="option0">question</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check" style="display:none;" id="contentRadioButton1">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="optionResult" id="option1" value="Dato 1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="option1">question</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check" style="display:none;" id="contentRadioButton2">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="optionResult" id="option2" value="Dato 2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="option2">question</label>
</div>

<button onclick="ResultTest()" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
```

El último método que intenté fue el siguiente pero me regresa un `undefined`:

```
function ResultTest(){
  let activoFijo = getElementsByName("optionResult").value;
}
```

Mi pregunta es ¿cómo puedo saber qué radio button fue seleccionado y traer el value con javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pon esto mejor:

```
function ResultTest(){
  let activoFijo = document.querySelector('input[name="optionResult"]:checked').value;
  console.log(activoFijo);
}
```

**Explicación:**

La función `querySelector` dice lo siguiente en [su documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

> Devuelve el primer elemento del documento (utilizando un recorrido
> primero en profundidad pre ordenado de los nodos del documento) que
> coincida con el grupo especificado de selectores.

En este caso concreto, el *primer elemento* a encontrar es un `<input>` que tiene de atributo de nombre (**name=**) `optionResult` y como selector CSS la [pseudoclase](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Pseudo-classes_and_pseudo-elements#las_pseudoclases) denominada `checked`, que **indica que está marcado**.  Al ser un conjunto de botones de radio *con el mismo nombre **solo uno** puede estar marcado*.

Por lo tanto el *grupo especificado de selectores* en este caso es:

```
input[name="optionResult"]:checked
```

La consulta con `querySelector` nos va a devolver un único *elemento* coincidente (el primero), por lo cual ya podemos intentar sacarle más información a continuación de la consulta, y como queremos saber el contenido de su [atributo de valor](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-value) (**value=**), le pasamos `.value` a dicho elemento.

Todo eso agrupado queda así:

```
document.querySelector('input[name="optionResult"]:checked').value;
```

que ya podemos asignar a lo que necesitemos después para trabajar con el.

Comment: Gracias, funciono!!!

Comment: Perfecto, luego lo documento un poco mas :-)